# Restore grub in Ubuntu

Tags: grub2

Every time I open my computer I have to press <kbd>F12</kbd> (Lenovo computer boot management) to be able to go to *Ubuntu* to get GRUB to choose *Ubuntu* Is there a way to to configure GRUB so that it's boot menu comes up directly, without the need to press <kbd>F12</kbd>?

[image]

[image]

Comment: id your bios (prolly f2 as you boot) you need to go to boot order and move ubuntu to the top of the list

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to go into your bios (likely `F2` at boot) and set your boot order so that Ubuntu disk is at the top of the list.